# In the Sources panel, Chrome Dev Tools says variable is undefined, but in the console panel, it has a value

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, console.log, chrome-debugging

When I open Chrome Dev Tools and I set a breakpoint in the sources panel, upon pausing at the breakpoint, Chrome tells me that the variable in question is `undefined`.

But when I type that variable into the console, (while still paused on the breakpoint) I get the correct value as expected.

Why is this happening?

I've made a GIF to illustrate the problem

[image: Chrome Dev Tools undefined issue]

Comment: It's a bug, see https://crbug.com.

Comment: Which bug Is it?

Comment: My idea was for you to find it. Try [this query](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=component%3APlatform%3EDevTools+summary%3Athis&sort=-modified&colspec=ID+Stars+Status+OS+Summary+Modified).